# Select columns ranges in a VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select a range (of values, the whole column) for the values: **FirstDate**, **EndDate** and **Number**. My VBA:

The Output of the below VBA  is highlighted (Column D) :

[image: Output]

```
Sub DateTest()
    Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim IntervalType As String
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim TempDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer
IntervalType = "m" ' "m" specifies MONTHS as interval.
FirstDate = Cells(1, 1).Value
EndDate = Cells(1, 2).Value
Number = Cells(1, 3).Value  ' "Number" For the syntax DateAdd.

' If the number is not greater than zero an infinite loop will happen.
If Number <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Number needs to be greater than 0", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

i = 1
Do Until TempDate = EndDate
   If i <= 1 Then
       TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, FirstDate)
   Else
       TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, TempDate)
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
Loop
Range("D1").Value = i - 1

End Sub
```

As I wrote before I want to run my Macro not only for the first 3 cells (currently the macro works fine for the value (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)), as you can see above for FirstDate, EndDate and Number

I want to use for all dates in Column1, Column2, Column3 for example:

[image: Description of my desired Output]

I already tried this:

```
Sub DateTest()
    Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim IntervalType As String
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim TempDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer

    IntervalType = "m" ' "m" specifies MONTHS as interval.

   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For lRow = 1 To lLastRow

   FirstDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    EndDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    Number = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value

    ' If the number is not greater than zero an infinite loop will happen.
    If Number <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Number needs to be greater than 0", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i = 1
    Do Until TempDate = EndDate
       If i <= 1 Then
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, FirstDate)
       Else
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, TempDate)
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
    Loop
    Range("D1").Value = i - 1

      Next
      End With

End Sub
```

But is still transforming the 1 row.

Comment: Have you tried the `Range().Resize()` function that expands the range from a single cell to a table of cells?

Comment: Are you asking how to run your code for the entire worksheet, with each row having a unique output? As of right now, your `FirstDate`,`EndDate` and `Number` variables have set ranges `(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)` so every time you loop it's looping back to those cell values. You need to change the range of your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you need correctly it's because you're calling out `Range("D1").Value` so it will always update that cell. You can make it more dynamic by using the `lRow` variable you already set up to place it into the correct row.
Replacing this `Range("D1").Value = i - 1` with this `Cells(lRow, 4).Value = i - 1`

```
Sub DateTest()
Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
Dim IntervalType As String
Dim Number As Integer
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim TempDate As Date
Dim i As Integer

IntervalType = "m" ' "m" specifies MONTHS as interval.

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

For lRow = 1 To lLastRow

FirstDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
EndDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
Number = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value

' If the number is not greater than zero an infinite loop will happen.
If Number <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Number needs to be greater than 0", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

i = 1
Do Until TempDate = EndDate
   If i <= 1 Then
       TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, FirstDate)
   Else
       TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, TempDate)
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
Loop
Cells(lRow, 4).Value = i - 1
'Range("D1").Value = i - 1

  Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one TheJeebo